# Is this ASCII type?

Tags: java, serial-port, char, ascii, inputstream

[image]

Is this ASCII ?

And how can I print it in understanding language like in char ?

I get this answer from my PortCom.
Here is how I read :

```
boolean ok = false;
int read = 0;
System.out.println("In Read :");
  while(ok == false) {
    int availableBytes = 0;
    try {
        availableBytes = inputStream.available();
        if (availableBytes > 0) {
            read = read + availableBytes;
            int raw = inputStream.read(readBuffer, read-availableBytes, availableBytes);
            System.out.println("Inpustream ="+raw);
            traduction = new String(readBuffer, read-availableBytes, availableBytes);
            System.out.println("2=>" + traduction);
            Response = new String(readBuffer, "UTF-8");             // bytes -> String
        } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    if (availableBytes == 0 && (read == 19 || read == 8)){
        ok = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use `InputStream` instead of `Reader` on purpose?

Comment: You can't tell if it's ASCII unless your print the numeric values of the characters. ASCII has several outdated, theoretically non-printable characters that could very well be what you're getting.

Comment: Yes, I use InputStream and OutputStream

Comment: @zneak : "theoretically non-printable" Oo that means I can't print them or there is still a way ?

Comment: You risk getting any binary value, which may result in "interesting" characters being printed.

Comment: Obviously, you do use it. My question was about the reason behind your refusal to use a `Reader` when that's clearly what you need.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Is this response convertible in binary then get the int value ?

Comment: @ Marko Topolnik : From what I understand from the "READER",is that it is used only to read from file. Here, I read from my serial port, soo does it work the same way ?

Comment: I do not understand what you ask.  The [?] character is most likely the glyph corresponding to ASCII 2 or 3 in your current font.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen : Need to see the char or int value of this ASCII 2 or 3 response. Just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read your comments, I am under the impression that you're a little confused as to what a character and ASCII are.

Characters are numbers. Plain dumb numbers. It just so happens that people created standard mappings between numbers and letters. For instance, according to the ASCII character *map*, 97 is `a`. The implications of this are that when display software sees 97, it knows that it has to find the glyph for the character `a` in a given font, and draw it to the screen.

Integer values 0 through 31, when interpreted with the ASCII character map, are so-called *control characters* and as such have no visual glyph associated with them. They tell software how to behave rather than what to display. For instance, the character #0 is the `NUL` character and is used to signal the end of a string with the C string library and has little to no practical use in most other languages. Off my head, character #13 is `NL`, for "new line", and it tells the rendering software to move the drawing cursor to the next line, rather than to render a character.

Most ASCII control characters are outdated and are not meant to be sent to text rendering software. As such, implementations decide how they deal with them if they don't know what to do. Many of them do nothing, some print question marks, and some print completely unrelated characters.

ASCII only maps integers from 0 to 128 to glyphs or control characters, which leaves another 128 possible integers in a byte undefined. Integers above 127 have no associated glyph in the ASCII standard, and only these can be called "not ASCII". So, what you should be asking, really, is "is that *text*?" rather than "is that *ASCII*?", because any sequence of integers between 0 and 127 is necessarily ASCII, which however says nothing about whether or not it's human-readable.

And the obvious answer to that question is "no, it's not text". Asking what it is if it's not text is asking us to be psychics, since there's no "universal bug" that maims text. It could be almost anything.

However, since you state that you're reading from a serial link, I'd advise you to check the bauds rate and other link settings, because there's no built-in mechanism to detect mismatches from on end to the other, and it can mangle data the way it does here.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I found what I wanted by doing Arrays.toString(readBuffer) and then I need to convert all my negatif in positif because the value doesn't go above 127.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **raw** value instead of availableBytes:

```
traduction = new String(readBuffer, read-availableBytes, raw);
```

The raw indicates how many were actually read as opposed to how many you requested. If you ask 10 bytes and it reads 5, the remaining 5 will be unknown garbage.

**UPDATE**

The response is obviously wrong too and for the same reason:

```
Response = new String(readBuffer, "UTF-8");
```

You are telling it to convert the entire buffer even though you may have only read 1 byte. If you're a bit unlucky you'll get exceptions because not all byte combinations can be converted using UTF-8

Comment: Yes, I already tried but it changes nothing to the response I get :/